# Using a ASP .NET MVC model value to validate another model value?

Tags: c#, validation, model, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
    public int DayTotal {get;set}
}
```

For this model class I am creating a custom ValidationAttribute for the 'DayTotal' property.  The custom validator will check the entered value 'DayTotal' value against another table that defines the maximum days allowed.

How to I refer to the selected 'EmployeeId' from the Create view when writing my query in the validator?

```
public class DayTotalAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var products = from p in db.EmployeeDayMax
                       where p.EmployeeId = ???
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

My solution has taken a different approach.  The helpful answers got me looking in other places.  This [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) from Scott Gu helped to provide a simpler approach:

In my model ->

```
   public class SomeClass : IValidateObject
   {
         public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
         public int DayTotal {get; set;}

         public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
            ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();
            //check maxes...can refer directly to EmployeeId in LINQ queries
            if(failed)
            {
               yield return new ValidationResult("Days have been maxed!");
            }
```

Comment: How do you pass in the validationContext when calling Validate(..)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[@Luke Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019615/using-a-asp-net-mvc-model-value-to-validate-another-model-value/5019694#5019694) is completely right, ValidationContext is new in MVC 3.

Here's an example using your code:

```
public class DayTotalAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var model = (SomeClass)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            var products = from p in db.EmployeeDayMax
                       where p.EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId

            bool somethingIsWrong = // do your validation here

            if (somethingIsWrong)
            {
                return ValidationResult("Error Message");
            }
        }

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I am getting close.  The line 'var (model) = (SomeClass..' compiles fine but throws a 'InvalidCastException' when I actually run the program and enter some values in.  Any ideas?

Comment: @John M: The Type of ObjectInstance should be the type of your ViewModel. So if you use ´SomeClass´ as the model of your view it should be fine. Can you see in the debugger what the actual type of ObjectInstance is?

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.0 there is [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022.aspx) for IsValid that takes a [ValidationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.aspx) parameter. This has an [ObjectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.objectinstance.aspx) property which you can cast to SomeClass and gives you access to its other properties.